# Dynamically generated class that implements IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() and IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()

Tags: c#, ienumerable, reflection.emit, ienumerator

I have a problem with Reflection.Emit. I want to have dynamically created class, that has simple implementation of ICollection. All methods I've defined fine, instead of next two: public IEnumerator GetEnumerator() & IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
Next code shows what I want to be in my dynamic class:

```
public class SomeClassThatIsIEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {...}

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {...}

}
```

This one is output from the Reflector opened my dynamic assembly:

```
public class SomeClassThatIsIEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable<T>
    {
        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        {
           ...
        }

        IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
        {
           ...
        }
    }
```

I'm defining my class In such way:

```
TypeBuilder myType = module.DefineType("myType"...);
myType.AddInterfaceImplementation(typeof(IEnumerable));
myType.AddInterfaceImplementation(typeof(IEnumerable<T>));
myType.AddInterfaceImplementation(typeof(ICollection<T>));
myType.DefineMethodOverride(myDefineGetEnumerator(...),typeof(IEnumerable).GetMethod("GetEnumerator");
myType.DefineMethodOverride(myDefineGetGenericEnumerator(...),typeof(IEnumerable<T>).GetMethod("GetEnumerator);
//Definitions of other ICollection methods
//Define GetEnumerator is looks like this:
MethodBuilder method = myType.DefineMethod("GetEnumerator", MethodAttributes.Final | MethodAttributes.Virtual...)
ILGenerator il = method.GetILGenerator();
// adding opcodes
```

when I call myType.CreateType TypeLoadException throws with message GetEnumerator method doesn't have implementation. I'm suggesting on problem with IEnumerable.GetEnumerator method, because I had problems in writing it on C#, not even in IL :). Can anyone help me?

Comment: What is it that you want the enumerator to *do*? Ultimately if you messing with `ILGenerator` you want to get *very* familiar with reflector and ildasm, to see what *it* generates, and understand why. This is such a big question/area that it is hard to give a simple answer...

Comment: I don't know way to generate dynamic assemblies otherwise ILGenerator. If you can get a hint on this I'll be very grateful to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is next define of the method

```
 MethodBuilder myMethod = myType.DefineMethod("System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator",
                   MethodAttributes.Private | MethodAttributes.HideBySig |
                MethodAttributes.NewSlot | MethodAttributes.Virtual | 
                MethodAttributes.Final);
```

It was amazing to me that writing an interface name in the name of the method would be to establish a unique relation with the interface

Answer (score 3):

It appears you should perhaps be using `DefineMethod` rather than `DefineMethodOverride`.  There is [an example of emitting an explicit interface implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder.definemethodoverride.aspx) on MSDN.  (I have not taken the time to try it however.)

Comment: Thanks for link, it was helpful, I've found out answer with your your help, but it was not your answer.